# Is it possible to make a row longer? I am trying to make our picture notification types look longer

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise

[image: Example]

We release notifications to our users to show them the risks of phishing scams. For our notifications, we put pictures in the "notification type" field to draw attention. To do so, we use a link to the photo. Does anyone have a workaround or a better way to make these pictures look larger?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use json format for this.

```
{
   "$schema": "http://columnformatting.sharepointpnp.com/columnFormattingSchema.json",
   "elmType": "div",
   "children": [
     {
       "elmType": "img",
       "attributes": {
         "src": "@currentField",
         "title": "=if(@currentField == '', 'No picture available', @currentField)"
       },
       "style": {
         "position": "relative",
         "top": "50%",
         "left": "50%",
         "width": "160px",
         "height": "auto",
         "margin-left": "-50%",
         "margin-top": "0%"
       }
     }
   ]
}
```

[image]

[refer this thread](https://blog.atwork.at/post/2018/12/04/Use-SharePoint-view-column-formatting-for-displaying-pictures-and-conditional-formatting)